# Change the output for `Times`function

Tags: output-formatting, core-language

When I have an input like:

```
1/2*k
```

The output is:

[image]

How to change the output of `Times`function to see this result:

[image]

Another option is to put all rational number using `Defer`function automatically.

Comment: `TraditionalForm[Defer[1/2  ] k ]`?

Comment: I would to like to change the function `Times`.

Comment: how about `Infix[1/2 k, "\[InvisibleTimes]"]`?

Comment: The problem is, every time I want to write a Rational number I will have to put `Infix.....` I want a way to program just in one line for every Rational number that I write from now on.

Comment: You want to look at the `Notation` package.  You certainly do *not* want to change the workings of `Times`---it's very deep down and all sorts of things depend on it working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just override the formatting of [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times):

```
MakeBoxes[Times[r_Rational, s_], StandardForm] := RowBox[{MakeBoxes[r], MakeBoxes[s]}]
MakeBoxes[Times[r_Rational, s__], StandardForm] := RowBox[{MakeBoxes[r], MakeBoxes[Times[s]]}]
```

Then:

```
k/2
```

[image]

Comment: Should the first FormatValue be `RowBox[{MakeBoxes[r], Parenthesize[s, StandardForm, Times]}]`?

Comment: @ChipHurst Yes, that would be a good idea, so that `1/2 (a+b)` formats correctly.

Comment: The problem is when I have a symbol in the denominator. For example, for `1/α*k` the output will be `k/α` because for Mathematica `1/α` is not a Rational number. How to change for the output be `1/α k`.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to change *notation*, not the way `Times` actually works.

You can try using a separator, as @kglr suggests in the comments.

```
<<Notation`
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
    RowBox[{"a_", "\[InvisibleTimes]", "b_"}]] 
    \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[
    RowBox[{"Times", "[", RowBox[{"a_", ",", "b_"}], "]"}]]]
```

After evaluating the above, when I type

```
k/2
```

I see

```
(1/2) k
```

But when I type `k/3/d` I see  `(1/3)((1/d)k)`.  So maybe more finesse is needed...

Comment: Update: you must <<Notation` first.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635701/preventing-notation-palette-from-popping-up you may want to set Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette=False at the beginning, when you're done fiddling with notation.